# Debugging the unknown error. Angular app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, javascriptcore

I am trying to get my ionic app.js running with my new factory and am having problems locate an error. I am not sure where but its probly a simple mistake.  If you can help me it would mean a lot. There is no errors in the the index and I have ng-app properly. Thank you

No ERROR: its just a blank screen :/ How do i debug?

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['allmystuff']);

(function() {
  'use strict';

  app

    .run(runFunction)
    .config(configFn)
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .factory('myService', myService);


  function runFunction($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    })
  }


  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'myService','$localStorage'];

  function MainCtrl($scope, myService, $localStorage) {
    function getSuccess(response) {
      $scope.items = response.data;
    }

    function getError(response) {
      console.log('Of course an error since the url is a invalid, but it should work with a valid url!');
    }

    myService.getAll()
      .then(getSuccess)
      .catch(getError);
  }

  function myService($http) {
    var factory = {
      getAll: getAll
    };

    return factory;

    function getAll() {
      return $http.get(""); 
    }
  }


function configFn($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      cache: false,
      controller: 'AccountCtrl',
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html"
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

}

});
```

Comment: Well, you haven't shown any HTML so there isn't a lot of information to go on, but I would imagine it would be hard to go to `/tab/dash` when there is no `.state` for that....

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');`

Where is your tab.dash state.

Maybe you mean /tab/account url

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/account');
```

Comment: i tried to remove some states to keep the code shorter. There is no error in the html as I have tested it without the factory and it worked.